# how to filter the string/list?

Tags: java, json, list, filter

I have a no. of arrays/list items in the format: (I am using Java)

```
{"scout": "webdriver", "short_version": "4.3", "long_name": "iPad", "api_name": "ipad", 

"long_version": "4.3.", "automation_backend": "webdriver", "os": "Mac 10.6"}
```

I only need :  `"os": "Mac 10.6"`
How to filter it using list/json ?

My array is got by:

```
String[] str = platformJsonContent.split("}");
```

Now i got list :

```
List<String> platforms = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
            platforms.add(str[i]);
        }
```

// filter should be here

Comment: Is there a language you're using to read this string?

Comment: Use [Json in Java](http://json.org/java/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably better to read it using JSONObject or others.

```
JSONObject platforms = new JSONOBject(platformJsonContent);

platforms.get("os");
#=> "Mac 10.6"
```

See further documentation here: http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

If you need it specifically as an array, it might be better to use JSONArray, which can be obtained from a JSONObject using the `.getJSONArray` method on JSONObject once it has been parsed.

http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

You will need to download and reference the JSON java package: http://www.json.org/java/json.org and then setup the references in whatever build system. Final code might look something like:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String platformJsonContent = "{\"scout\": \"webdriver\", \"short_version\": \"4.3\", \"long_name\": \"iPad\", \"api_name\": \"ipad\", \"long_version\": \"4.3.\", \"automation_backend\": \"webdriver\", \"os\": \"Mac 10.6\"}";

            JSONObject platforms = new JSONObject(platformJsonContent);

            System.out.println(platforms.get("os"));
        } catch(JSONException ex) {
            // do something...
        }
    }
}
```

This runs and outputs "Mac 10.6"

Comment: its not working.. When debugger comes on declaration line, it breaks the function.

Comment: can I get more description of the error? You may need to include the JSON library. So copy paste might not be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using JEE7, then have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you decide not to use any libraries, here is one way you can get your "os"

```
//Assuming your jsonString is like this - "\"long_version\": \"4.3.\", \"automation_backend\": \"webdriver\", \"os\": \"Mac 10.6\""
Map<String, String> pairs = getJsonMap(jsonString);
pairs.get("os")
```

Here's how you can do getJsonMap()

```
    private Map<String,String> getJsonMap(String jsonString){
        String[] eachPair = jsonString.replaceAll("\"", "").split(",");
        Map<String,String> pairs = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for(String pair: eachPair) {
            pairs.put(pair.substring(0, pair.indexOf(":")).trim(), pair.substring(pair.indexOf(":")+1));
        }
        return pairs;
    }
```

I would still strongly recommend you to look at JSON support for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Boon has the fastest JSON parser on the JVM circa March 2014 and it has slice notation lib.

So.....

Given this JSON:

```
    String json = "{\"scout\": \"webdriver\", \"short_version\": \"4.3\", \"long_name\": \"iPad\", \"api_name\": \"ipad\", \n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"long_version\": \"4.3.\", \"automation_backend\": \"webdriver\", \"os\": \"Mac 10.6\"}";
```

You can "filter it" like this:

```
    System.out.println( atIndex( fromJson(json), "os" ) ); //one line of code
```

Output:

```
Mac 10.6
```

You can learn more about Boon here: http://www.dzone.com/links/1091051.html
And here: http://rick-hightower.blogspot.com/2014/03/boon-filtering-for-java-beans-json-and.html

Boon allows you to parse JSON, serialize Java objects to JSON, dependency inject JSON, marshal JSON to method calls, marshal JSON to constructor calls, search indexed JSON, actually filtering JSON, and sort JSON. If you can think of something you would like to do with JSON, Boon probably does it.

https://github.com/RichardHightower/boon

(For a moment... it seemed like I was channeling a scene from Forrest Gump. You can fry shrimp, bake shrimp, steam shrimp. There is shrimp gumbo, and ....)